# React image redirect to another page when click on it in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

Here is my code. It is not working. I want that if anyone clicks on this image it will move to the men's category page.

```
<TouchableOpacity >
       <Image source={require("../assets/mens.png")} style={{ width: 50, height: 50, borderRadius: 20 }} onPress={() => navigation.navigate(MensCategory)}/>
       </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> // Move function call}>
<Image source={require("../assets/mens.png")} style={{ width: 50, height: 50, borderRadius: 20 }} onPress={() => navigation.navigate(MensCategory)}/>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Above, i Mention the Logic, Try Again
Move it to respective page

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`onPress` callback should be applied to `TouchableOpacity` component. Move it to there from `Image`.

Comment: Still not working

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to pass a string on navigate method. So its like,

```
() => navigation.navigate("MensCategory")
```